# Restore failed for Server 'Server path'. Microsoft.SqlExpress.Express.Smo

Tags: sql-server

I get this error when i try to restore my database.

Additional Information:
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided.

Any suggestions? Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like when the backup was taken it was striped with another media.  Because of this, the combination of both of these would constitute a full backup.  Therefore, just like the message says, you need both of the backup files.

Comment: I followed your instruction. But now new problem occurred. The restoring process is only up to 50%. It does not move anymore.